# TTLauncher View of Three20 not working

Tags: iphone, three20, ttlauncherview

I have followed a tutorial to make a simple launcher view like in facebook app. But nothing is displayed on screen when program runs and it shows only a white screen. I dont know why this is happening plz help.

The tutorial i followed is at [I have followed a tutorial to make a simple launcher view like in facebook app. But nothing is displayed on screen when program runs and it shows only a white screen. I dont know why this is happening plz help.

The tutorial i followed is at http://iosguy.com/2010/10/19/tthree20-a-brief-ttlauncherview-tutorial .]1 .

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. The solution that worked for me was to set the background of my "MainWindow.xib" to "Clear Color" (default is "White Color"). 
If you have no xib, you can still set the color in your AppDelegate: `[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Comment: but in my case there is no MainWindow.xib in the tutorial files, but its working and not working when i used it in separate project.

Answer (score 1):

if u need only launcher effect , better try this , light weight library

https://github.com/rigoneri/myLauncher

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the method:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
```

is lacking at the end:

```
[navigator.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If you need more help, please, post your code...

Comment: have you tried adding `makeKeyAndVisible`? would you check in you applicationDelegate what value has navigator.window before exiting the method?

Comment: when i run the code downloaded from site it works perfect, but then i created a new project and included three20 library through python script and copied the code given in tutorial, but then its not working, its showing only white blank screen.